# Fresh Install of Visual Studio Cannot Debug

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, mono

I have just installed Visual Studio Community for Mac, but cannot get any of the pages I've created to debug and show in browser.

I reinstalled and created a .aspx page with a small amount of html on it to test, but I keep getting this error:

Description:

> HTTP 404.The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies)
>   could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is
>   spelled correctly.

The 4 missing files all belong to this file path:

> /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/

I have installed mono for Mac but the file path Visual Studio is after doesn't seem to exist despite this. I have tried searching forums for a solution, but I don't think I'm phrasing the problem properly, can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: I am getting the same error. I am not able to solve. Can you guide, if you were able to solve error.